# Connecting Wix domain with Vultr Managed Wordpress website

Tags: domains, wordpress, wix

I'm having a hard time getting a Wix domain to work with Vultr managed Wordpress website.  Currently I have both IPv4 and IPv6 from Vultr.  I made sure that the domain is not assigned to a Wix website.  I also went to `Domains > Advanced`. Under DNS Records, I made sure that the host name is pointing to the IPv4 address.

I went to Wordpress, `Settings > General`.  I entered the same IPv4 into Wordpress Address and Site Address

Now when I point my browser to that IPv4 address, I get the Wix.com error page, `"Looks Like This Domain Isn't Connected to a Website Yet!"`

From my previous experience, also entering the IPv6 into the domain website (e.g. Google Domains), seemed to have fixed this issue, however Wix does not support IPv6 for their domains.

I'm thinking that maybe I need to transfer the domain out of Wix and move it elsewhere, like Google Domains.

Before I do that though, anyone know if I can get it to work without transferring it out?

Right now since the ip address is redirecting to the domain, `/wp-admin` isn't accessible...

Answer (score 1):

I helped transfer a site out of Wix.   Wix allows you to use them as a domain registrar and DNS host without a Wix site.  They are able to point your domain to external hosting.

Rather than editing `Settings > General` you should be [editing your DNS settings](https://support.wix.com/en/article/editing-dns-records-in-your-wix-account).

> #### To edit DNS records:
>
> 1. Go to the [My Domains](https://premium.wix.com/wix/api/mpContainerStaticController#/domains) page.
>      Note: If you have more than one domain in your account, select the relevant domain.
> 2. Click the **Advanced** tab.
> 3. Click **Edit DNS**.
> 4. Edit the relevant records.
> 5. Click **Save DNS**.

You will need to change the `A` records for `www.` and the domain apex (usually denoted by `@`).  Put in your new host's IP address for both those records.

I would suggest transferring your domain to another registrar at some point. Wix has reasonable domain registration prices, but their main business is building websites, not registering domains.   I recommend using a domain registrar whose main business is registering domains.